# Out of heap space, -Xmx1024m cause "Cannot Access Jarfile" error

Tags: java, memory, heap-memory, space

I'm trying to run a program called PatchusMaximus.jar, which is a patching application for PerkusMaximus, a mod for Skyrim. I'm also running something called ModOrganizer, which creates virtual directories to prevent overwriting and loss of files and crashing. The issue I keep getting is when I run the .jar file from MO, it gives me the error:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

The most common, and only answer I can find is to run the program from the .bat file or add "`-Xmx1024m`" at the beginning of the script, after javaw.exe. Some told me to also add "`-NOSTREAM`" at the end. When I do this, the patcher doesn't even run. When running the .bat file as administrator (which has -Xmx1024m in it), I get a message telling me "Cannot Access Jarfile PatchusMaximus.jar". Can someone tell or point me to a solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: would you please post your complete command line?

Comment: Have you tries raising the maximum heap memory to a higher value that 1 GB? The mod may contain high detail graphics that occupy a lot of space.

Comment: Please post the contents of your .bat and the script.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, the BAT is:
'javaw.exe -Xmx1024m -jar "PatchusMaximus.jar" "-NOSTREAM"'

And yes, I've tried -Xmx2048m.